# Can't apply an onClick function to <TableRowColumn> in React with Material-UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I formerly had functionality whereby I could click on the cell of a `table` and it would toggle the colour of the text between red and green.

I have since implemented Material-UI in the React app, replacing the `<td>` tags with `<TableRowColumn>` tags, to which now I find that the onClick event no longer works.

I have tested the functionality of onClick by placing a `<button>` within the `<TableRowColumn>`, which **DOES** infact work. So this leads me to believe that the `<TableRowColumn>` element does not have the option for onClick...

**Working**

```
return (
        <tdstyle={taskStyle} onClick={this.props.toggleTask.bind(this, task)}>
            {task} <button >Click</button>
        </td>
    )
```

**Broken (The colour change functionality works when called from the button)**

```
return (
        <TableRowColumn style={taskStyle} onClick={() => this.help()}>
            {task} <button onClick={this.props.toggleTask.bind(this, task)} >Click</button>
        </TableRowColumn>
    )
```

**Function**

```
toggleTask(task) {
    const foundToDo = _.find(this.state.todos, todo => todo.task === task);
    foundToDo.isCompleted = !foundToDo.isCompleted;
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos });
  }
```

Comment: Which material-UI version are you using?

Comment: The latest one: 0.20.0 - I literally picked up using Material-UI today.

Comment: I guess you are not using material-UI v1 if so then in earlier versions TableRowColumn doesn’t have onClick props. Since you started material-UI Very recently then I would advise you to use latest version which is materia-ui@next The table components are completely changed in latest version with advanced features. Many new features are introduced in latest version.

Comment: OH! I saw the website and followed their instructions for downloading - Made it look like v1 was coming soon, but not here yet. I just did a npm install of material-ui

Comment: You can install latest version  using npm install —save material-ui@next. Version V1 has so many changes, if you use older version now then in future if you want to upgrade to v1 then you will have to do many changes and you will face so many difficulties while upgrading to v1. So start using v1 from now. Again It’s very powerful and so many features in V1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @HemadriDasari - I'll give it a go and report back :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add an `onCellClick` function to the Table component that takes the row and column indices as parameters.

```
handleCellClick(row, column, e) {
if(row == 0)
   ...
if(column == 0)
   ...
}
```

You may have to implement a way to lookup the task based its column & row. This would handle changing the color of the cell's text

Comment: I saw the onCellClick tag earlier but wasn't aware of passing in rows, columns etc. I suppose I could try to use this for something like: if(column == 0) { blahh } else { return }